# Copy specific entire column from file 1 to 2

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I'm trying to copy columns C, R, W,X from file 1 to file 2 with below code but keep getting an error. My VBA knowledge isn't that good yet but probably has to do with the range setting? I've tried multiple ways but can't get it to work.

Am I using the right setting or should I use another action to get the specific columns?

```
Sub PFS()

Dim wbCopy As Workbook
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim wbPaste As Workbook
Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
Dim rngPaste As Range

Set wbPaste = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("path to copy")
Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("Blad1")
Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("d, e").EntireColumn
Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Worksheets("PFS")
Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range("a1")

rngCopy.Copy
rngPaste.PasteSpecial

Workbooks.Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbCopy.Save
wbCopy.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: where you have `"path to copy"` you do have your `full path & "\" & FileName.xlsx` , right ? when using `PasteSpecial` you need to add a parameter of which type, like `xlPasteAll` or `xlPasteValues` after, like `rngPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`.

Comment: If you want to use your `wsCopy.Range("d, e").EntireColumn` method, then modify it to `Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("D1:E1").EntireColumn`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I do have the full path, I just removed it as it`s a long reference with company references.  If I put in the wsCopy.Range ("D1:E1").Entire column it takes everything in between right? as I need C,R,W and X. Anyway to leave the columns out I dont need?

Comment: You can use `Union` method to select separate ranges. I just don't know how that will be pasted, probably also separately, exactly in the same position as it was in original worksheet.

Comment: Ok found out myself, should replace the line with Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("C:C,R:R,W:W,X:X").EntireColumn

Comment: I think you don't need `.EntireColumn` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to copy entire column.

```
Sub copy()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("old")
    Set wbNew = Workbooks("Book.xlsx")
    Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("new")

    ws.Columns(3).copy
    wsNew.Columns(3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    ws.Columns(18).copy
    wsNew.Columns(18).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    ws.Columns(23).copy
    wsNew.Columns(23).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    ws.Columns(24).copy
    wsNew.Columns(24).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Set wsNew = Nothing
    Set wbNew = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```